# How to play diminished 9th chord in guitar ( chord shape )?

Tags: guitar, chords, jazz

How to play `diminished 9th` chord in a guitar ? Please provide some common shapes to play...

Comment: Do you mean a chord like C7b9, or perhaps rather Cm9b5, or Cminmaj9b5? Please clarify. Also, the internet is full of chord diagrams. It would help if you could clarify if you need help with: a) understanding what chord do you want to play or b) finding notes of that chord or c) finding those notes on the guitar fretboard?

Comment: @user1079505 Agreed: this is easily found with a simple web search. (A typical DV reason, FWIW.) Diminished 9th chords are defined as fully diminished seventh chords with an added (major) 9th. (Minor ninths are also possible, but would be specifically indicated.) Interestingly, dim9 chords are equivalent note-wise to 7b9 chords: for example, Cdim9 has the same notes as D7b9. The request for common shapes seems pretty clear that the question regards fret board positions.

Comment: @Aaron yes. When I search I couldn't find out the commonly used chord shapes ( fret board positions )

Comment: @Prabhu My feeling is that this question doesn't demonstrate sufficient research — I found answers with one search. So rather than leave an answer post here, I've left an answer for you in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the guitar structure itself, there are lots of shapes and voicings for this chord. On the web you can find lots and lots of shapes, but my personal favorite, because of its box shape and usability in any place of the fretboard:

[image: Cdim(9)]

You can move this shape using the root (C in the case) as your guide!

Comment: I know it’s hard to grab every necessary chord tone in guitar voicings but the exclusion of Gb will make this sound as much or more like a Cm6/9 than a Cdim(9).

Comment: Well, as the b5 is much like a character tone in this chord, that is true, depending on the context. If the harmonic framework showed until the moment that chord is played, or even the other instruments playing, it can sound more or less like a dim or a minor chord.  Of course trying and experimenting is the best to know if it fits or not